# Failure at Maven clean deploy

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins pipeline I try to build in the  Maven Surefire Plugin so I can run Maven Test within the Pipeline and ignore the failure of the Test (so that the pipeline process can go on):

```
mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

However if I try to use the command I get following error:

```
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.UnaryMinusExpression, with its value 'Dmaven.test.failure.ignore', is a bad expression as the left hand side of an assignment operator at line: 6 column: 51. File: WorkflowScript @ line 6, column 51.
   oy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
                                 ^
```

I don't quite understand why it won't work, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line call of Maven is interpreted as groovy command. This means that you made a syntax error in your groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use the pipeline maven plugin and run the maven call with a shell step:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin

Example:

```
withMaven(
        // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
        maven: 'M3',
        // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
        // Maven settings and global settings can also be defined in Jenkins Global Tools Configuration
        mavenSettingsConfig: 'my-maven-settings',
        mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {

      // Run the maven build
      sh "mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe reports and FindBugs reports
```